# Processing of the file names

Tags: bash, variables

I have a folder with a files inside with a long names like:

08_29_2017.AT1_dry_apo.3rep.step7_1.xtc

each file begins with a current data in a format like
dd_mm_yyyy.

My bash script loops all the files and defines only the relevant part of the file name in a new variable:

```
for traj in ${all_xtc}/*.xtc; do
 traj_name3=$(basename "$traj")
 traj_name="${traj_name3/.xtc/}" # here I remove xtc from the name
 # here I need to add something to remove the date from the begining of the file
```

what should be passed here to remove a date from the beginning of a file name?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back and update your question; in particular it would help if you provided sample inputs and the desired outputs

Comment: @markp the OP provided a sample input and the desired output is pretty clear

Comment: yes and no; what is ${all_xtc}? does the OP need to maintain the path prefix; and while I can guess at what the OP wants as expected output, there's less room for confusion if OP were to explicitly show the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want in two parameter expansions:

```
for traj in "$all_xtc"/*.xtc; do
    traj=${traj##*/[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
    traj=${traj%.xtc}
    echo "$traj"
done
```

The first one removes everything up to the last slash (equivalent to `basename`), followed by the date. The second one removes the `.xtc` from the end.

The first expansion isn't at all strict about the date, since it would also match 98_76_0000, but it's probably good enough in this case. You can add a `.` to the end if you want to remove that as well.